# Ubuntu C How to stop child process using SIGTSTP then resume it using SIGCONT?

Tags: c, multithreading, process, signals, fork

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int pid = 0;

// some very time-consuming function
void childLabor() {
    for (long long i=1;i<=10000000000;i++) {
        //printf("i'm printing\n");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
}

// stop the process who calls this
void stopYourself() {
    // TODO
}

void childReceiveStop() {
    signal(SIGTSTP, childReceiveStop);
    printf("I have important things to do first before stopping\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    // do important things

    printf("I stop myself now\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    stopYourself();
}

void childReceiveContinue() {
    signal(SIGCONT, childReceiveContinue);
}

int main()
{
    pid = fork();
    if (pid==0) {
        signal(SIGTSTP, childReceiveStop);
        signal(SIGCONT, childReceiveContinue);
        stopYourself();     // wait until parent sends SIGCONT
        childLabor();
    }
    else {
        // start/stop child every 2 second
        kill(pid,SIGCONT);
        for (int i=1; i<=100; i++) {
            printf("sending signal stop\n");
            fflush(stdout);
            kill(pid, SIGTSTP);
            sleep(3);

            printf("sending signal start\n");
            kill(pid, SIGCONT);
            sleep(1);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Basically what I want to do in this example is let the child print for 3 seconds, then stop it, then let it print again, ... When the child receives SIGTSTP, it should stop. And when it receives SIGCONT, it should continue.

However, with or without handler, when the child process receives the SIGTSTP signal, it does not stop at all.

How can I fix this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`SIGTSTP` for sending stop signal from the terminal to a process. In your case, you ant to send stop signal from parent process. So you'd need `SIGSTOP` instead of `SIGTSTP`. So replace `SIGTSTP` with `SIGSTOP`.

Also `SIGSTOP` can't caught. So you don't need to have handlers for `SIGSTOP`.

Comment: what if I want the child process to do something before it is SIGSTOP-ed ?

Comment: Can't do with `SIGSTOP`. Perhaps use `SIGUSR1` or `SIGUSR2` instead?

Comment: Then how I tell the process to stop when it receives SIGUSR1 ?

Comment: For example, the child process on receipt of `SIGUSR1` could putself to sleep via a *condition variable* and could continue on signal.

Comment: can you explain more about "sleep via a condition variable" ? while (something==false) { } doesn't count because that means I have to add that statement after every normal statement in my code